# Internet Explorer shows 404 but web app is still running

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, internet-explorer, informix

I'm developing a web app with Spring, Hibernate and Informix...

It has a data importing process that takes up to 30 minutes, and while the user is waiting for it to end Internet Explorer shows an error telling the user that the page cannot be displayed, but the web app is still running (it keeps writing logs and importing data).

Why does this happen? Is it because it takes so long to show the resulting jsp?

How can I avoid this?

Thank you.

Comment: 404 is for a particular resource not found. Is the user trying to access the same resource which is not yet ready (until 30 minutes)? And really, 30 minutes?

Comment: Its preferable to do such imports using AJAX (i.e. background thread). It is impossible to tell you how it could be implemented particular in your case, because this is a very common solution, depends on concrete framework.

Comment: It happened during a stress test, forcing the app to import thousands of data, with a process that is only run once a month and yes, it takes 30 minutes... there's no other way of importing the data the app needs... it processes medical data...

Comment: Does the application really respond with a 404, or is IE just timing out? If you make a request while the data load is still in progress, I think there'd be no response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your browser waits 30 minutes to response and shows error page if there is no response within this time. There are various solutions for such a problem. Example: it is stress test, so you can run it at night (or other time when servers are not working hard) using cron and command line "browser" (like wget) and saving results into temp table. Then instead of starting tests from browser you can show results from this temp table.

Other idea: from your browser start background thread that will be filling temp table and display partial results with "Refresh" button. Action from this button will just read temp table. Add special record that will mean "end of tests", and show "refresh" when you will not find that special record.